# Find the greatest common divisor of $2^{2004}-1$ and $2^{2002}-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find the greatest common divisor of $2^{2004}-1$ and $2^{2002}-1$.

Using Euclidean algorithm:

$$2^{2004}-1=4(2^{2002}-1)+3$$
$$2^{2002}-1=x\cdot 3+y$$

The solution manual says that $2^{2002}-1$has the remainder $0$ when divided by $3$, that is $y=0$ so GCD is $3$. But how do I find that remainder?

Comment: What is $2^{2002}-1 \mod 3$?

Comment: @LeonSot That's my question, yes.

Comment: $2\equiv -1 \mod 3$. Hence $2^{2002}\equiv (-1)^{2002} \equiv 1 \mod 3$.

Comment: Also, @labbhattacharjee I would disagree that this question is a duplicate. Just because you can use that answer to answer this one, the linked question is much more general and the answers for it are overkill for this question.

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$2^{2002} -  1$

$= (2^4)^{500}.2^2 - 1$

Now $2^4 \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$

From above,

$= (1)^{500} .2^2 - 1$

$= 1.2^2 - 1$

$= 4 - 1 = 3$

Divisible by 3.

Comment: How is $(2^4)^{500}\cdot 2^2 - 1=1^{500}\cdot 2^2-1$?

Comment: $2^4 = 16 (mod 3) = 1$

Comment: Or simply you divide 16 by 3 them  remainder 1 and power of 1 is any equals to 1.